# codeigniter 2.0 and ajax

Tags: ajax, session, codeigniter

I just want to store a variable from jQuery into a session.

js file:

```
$.post("controller/ajaxtest","hello");
```

I am able to see this post request in firebug.  How can I access this variable or store it in the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data you are sending to a JSON object or a query string, then you can access it in PHP via `$_POST` or CodeIgniter's `$this->input->post`

```
$.post("controller/ajaxtest","var=hello");
```

OR

```
$.post("controller/ajaxtest",{"var":"hello"});
```

Then in `ajaxtest`, you can access it via `$this->input->post('var')`.

*NOTE*: If you do `$.post("controller/ajaxtest","hello");`, you are sending a post variable called `hello` with no value (`$_POST['hello']` will exist, but be empty).

**UPDATE**: To get this value back in your JavaScript, you can either make another AJAX call to a PHP script to retrieve it, or you can pass it to your view from the controller.

*AJAX Method*:

CI Controller

```
function getval(){
  $data = array('val' => 'Hello');
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

JavaScript

```
$.getJSON("controller/getval", function(data){
  alert(data.val); //Hello
});
```

*Controller -> View Method*:

CI Controller

```
function index(){
  $data['val'] = 'Hello';
  $this->load->view('page', $data);
}
```

And then in your view:

```
<script>
  var val = '<?=$val?>';
  alert(val); //Hello
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm. How would I now retrive that value or session value in jquery?

Comment: @user742736: You can either make an AJAX call to a page to get the value, or you can pass it to the view when you are loading the page.